# Why does ruby think this variable is a call to a method?

Tags: ruby

```
class Constants
    @@pi = 3.14
end

puts(ConstantContainer.pi)
```

I'm getting the following error: `undefined method 'pi' for ConstantContainer:Class (NoMethodError)`

How do I tell ruby that `pi` is a class variable not a method?

edit: i know this is very improper for defining constants, but I needed a quick way of demonstrating class variables.

Comment: While you say this is more of an example than anything, I can’t not note that it would probably make more sense here to do `module Constants; PI = 3.14; end`. Then again [`Math::PI`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Math.html#PI) is already built-in…

Comment: pi is not a variable. Ruby does not think it is a method, it is (at the parse level) a method.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes) is a decent read on classes in Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in a method, of course

```
class Constants
    @@pi = 3.14

    def self.pi
      @@pi
    end
end

Constants.pi # => 3.14
```

Or do the ugly `class_variable_get`

```
class Constants
    @@pi = 3.14
  end

Constants.class_variable_get(:@@pi) # => 3.14
```

Comment: Ah this makes sense. Coming from objective-C, i am too used to properties generating "getter" methods for me. Thank you!

Comment: One thing, could you explain to me why `def self.pi` works when defining the method but `def pi` doesn't work? I assume it's to prevent clashing between the identifiers of the method and the variable, am I right?

edit: I realize now, because it is a class method.

Comment: `def pi` generates an instance method which is accessible via an *instance* of the class (that is, `Constants.new`, not `Constants`). `def self.pi` generates a class instance method which works on the class itself.

Comment: @ByronS `def self.pi` defines a class method - `def pi` defines an instance method. To call an instance method, you need an instance of the class (so you'd need to do `Constants.new.pi` if you used `def pi`, but of course creating an instance of a class like `Constants` is pointless).

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question at all.

Comment: @sawa: OP thinks it does :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I see. That means the question is not clear. :)